# Apache Camel header set to null after performing a get

Tags: java, apache-camel

What could cause a header to be set to null as a result of getting it from the exchange?

My current workaround is to set the header again after reading but this is terribly hacky.

Example:

```
String header = exchange.getIn().getHeader("headerKey", String.class);
String theSameHeader = exchange.getIn().getHeader("headerKey", String.class);
System.out.printf("header is %s.\n", (header == null) ? "null" : "not null");
System.out.printf("theSameHeader is %s.\n", (theSameHeader == null) ? "null" : "not null");
```

Output:

```
header is not null.
theSameHeader is null.
```

Comment: Are you header a String type, it does however smell as if the header type is streaming based, and then you end up as what is described in this FAQ: http://camel.apache.org/why-is-my-message-body-empty.html

Comment: @ClausIbsen You are quite correct, I was reading from a stream. If you would like to post an answer I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you header a String type, it does however smell as if the header type is streaming based, and then you end up as what is described in this FAQ:

- http://camel.apache.org/why-is-my-message-body-empty.html